# HTML Align navbar to the right, image fitting page

Tags: html, css, image, navbar

I'm starting ton code and I have some struggles with this website. First, I made the header with a nabber in it but I can't align it to the right, if I try it with float:right it switches the links. And underneath all that I want a big picture but auto height and width doesn't work if I make the page bigger.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<style>


    header{ background-color: white;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 30px;
    }
    img.logo{ width: 200px;
              height: 30px;
    }

    li{ display: inline;
    }

    ul{ position: fixed;
        top: 20px;

    }

    a{  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    }

    img.picvp{margin-top: 20px;
              width: auto;
              height: auto;
    }

</style>
```

```
<header>

      <img class="logo" src="#">

    <ul>
        <li style="float:right;"><a href="Site%20DIA%20main.html">Projecten</a></li>
        <li style="float:right;"><a href="#">over</a></li>
        <li style="float:right;"><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</header>

<sec>
  <img class="picvp" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/G3M2vxtCatAm1yxWxUA0VVLZjtePu32ziMPd6TLL3wQhk53s4mokl5v_7Rx0crGBp_2Q6iZJnRU-lzQ=w1262-h905">
</sec>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `display:flex` will  help with this.

```css
.header{
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.logo{
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
.nav {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.nav li{ display: inline-block; }
.nav a {
  border-left: solid 1px;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
}
img.picvp{
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

      <img class="logo" src="#">

    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="Site%20DIA%20main.html">Projecten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">over</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</header>

<sec>
  <img class="picvp" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/G3M2vxtCatAm1yxWxUA0VVLZjtePu32ziMPd6TLL3wQhk53s4mokl5v_7Rx0crGBp_2Q6iZJnRU-lzQ=w1262-h905">
</sec>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the solution: [Fiddle N1](https://jsfiddle.net/5rd3r916/)

You just needed to add:  `width: 100%;` to the class `img.picvp`.
Another thing is that you should've set your `ul` elements like that:

```
 ul{ 
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    text-align:right;
    }
```

`text-align:right` automatically pulls the elements to the right side of the parent div. Also use `relative` positioning rather than fixed one. I have made some changes to the width of the background image as well. Compare the changes to the code so you can see what exactly has been changed.

Comment: Oke thanks, but I want the navbar to stick to the top so I need to have the positioning fixed or not?

Comment: well in this case just change it to fixed. Feel free to accept my answer if it has helped you..

Answer (score 0):

hii i modify some of code but impornant i use parent and child an example in your  i use  as parent and

as child see example as follow
(dont forgot to change img src)

```
header{ background-color: white;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 30px;
}
img.logo{ 


width: 1100px;
          height: 130px;
}

ul,li{ display: inline;
text-decoration:none;


}
```

`a,li{
display: inline;`

`}`

```
a{  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: inline;
}

img.picvp{margin-top: 20px;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
}
```

```
  <img class="logo" src="nows.jpg">

<ul>
    <li style="float:right;"><a href="Site%20DIA%20main.html">Projecten</a></li>
    <li style="float:right;"><a href="#">over</a></li>
    <li style="float:right;"><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```